# Is there a good dataflow concurrent library in java

Tags: java, clojure, dataflow

I'm currently looking at the dataflow model of concurrency as in Clojure and Groovy GPars. Is there any libraries written in pure Java that I can benefit from?

I know I can import or delegate to Clojure or Java, but I would like a nice and dedicated java API if possible.

Comment: Go on, write one, it is not so hard as you think... :-)

Comment: I know, but I had too many re-invents already in the shed, and wanted the external support :)

Comment: In java a don't know of such a system, but in javascript there is [noflo](https://github.com/noflo/noflo) which is a proof of concept lib I think. In my opinion it is not required to write every single line of code with dataflow components. I will write my own js lib, and I'll use dataflow code islands only to help async coding, and write everything else with sync code just as usual... The concept is good, but I don't think it is the golden hammer for everything...

Comment: https://github.com/jpaulm/javafbp There is a lib, but I am uncertain if this is what you are looking for, since you use the dataflow term, but not the dataflow programming... I guess I am ready to sleep, I fail to understand what I read. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [Akka](http://akka.io)'s dataflow module. It's underlying future/promises abstractions have a dedicated Java API, but the dataflow module is designed to be used from Scala. But depending on your exact needs, Akka's futures and promises could be enough. And they are very well designed, implemented and documented. There is even a book dedicated Akka's futures.

Comment: I tried akka a while back (version 1.3) for the actor and stm (multiverse) stuff, but found the actor library too scala bound for my liking. I can suspect this would be similar for the dataflow module?

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but afaik akka is an actor based and not a dataflow based solution. Btw. there are common things in both of these terms, so it can be used for dataflow based programming with actor based constraints, but I am not sure this kind of solution is for everyone. For example I don't like the one resource - one actor concept. (I never used akka.)

Comment: An interesting article in the topic which compares actors and dataflow programming: http://www.drdobbs.com/database/dataflow-programming-handling-huge-data/231400148

Comment: The actor and data flow models are quite different, indeed. But, I was specifically talking about Akka's data flow module which has been discontinued by now, if I'm correct.

Answer (score 1):

[df4j](https://github.com/rfqu/df4j) is, literally, "Data Flow For Java". I consider it as a good library, but note, I am the author :).

Comment: Sorry, I had a preliminary glance. Isn't this just an actor library rather than a dataflow library? It seems to depend on actors receiving messages rather than reading bound dataflow variables?

Comment: @Niels There are many variants of dataflow model, and no one library can implement all of them. df4j has bound dataflow variables (class CallbackFuture), but actors are not allowed to read them, only to write (bind). Only threads can read dataflow variables. This is because reading unbound variable blocks the underlying thread, actors are executed on a thread pool, and soon all threads in the pool may be blocked. If you want to use dataflow variables by large number of actors (exceeding the number of threads), you have to use bytecode rewriting, as in http://www.malhar.net/sriram/kilim.